# How can I install FreeNX server?

Tags: 10.10, installation, freenx

I was following the [instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX) but got this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv F3A662B57D580D3A2E98E5152A8E3034D018A4CE
gpg: requesting key D018A4CE from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
?: keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection timed out
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection timed out
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

**UPDATE**

Apparntley this was a proxy issue. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/443404. I solved it by:

```
$ sudo http_proxy=http://myproxy:8080 add-apt-repository ppa:freenx-team
```

and continued following the instructions. Now I have another problem:

```
$ sudo /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup --install
------> It is recommended that you use the NoMachine key for
        easier setup. If you answer "y", FreeNX creates a custom
        KeyPair and expects you to setup your clients manually. 
        "N" is default and uses the NoMachine key for installation.

 Do you want to use your own custom KeyPair? [y/N] 
/usr/lib/nx/nxsetup: line 140: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
Setting up  ...mkdir: missing operand
Try `mkdir --help' for more information.
```

Comment: @hhlp: I didn't get it. Should I just wait for a ppa? What can I do in the meanwhile? I really need my freenx server running.

Comment: @hhlp I tried, although I do not want that option. Anyway, I get the same error.

Comment: @hhlp not a single sole there...

Answer (score 2):

you can do it yourself

## Add this PPA to it's own list file

sudo bash -c "echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/freenx-team/ppa/ubuntu VERSION main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/freenx-team/ppa/ubuntu VERSION main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/freenx.list"

where VERSION can be: dapper, hardy, intrepid, lucid or **maverick** . More information can be found at FreeNX Team PPA.

Add the public key of FreeNX PPA run:

sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com F3A662B57D580D3A2E98E5152A8E3034D018A4CE

Then Update Apt

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
>
> sudo aptitude install Freenx

(note, as of Aug. 16 2010 the above command doesn't install a particular script file--appears to be missing from package. So after performing the above, download it from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/freenx-server/+bug/576359/+attachment/1378450/+files/nxsetup.tar.gz/%22here%22). Next, cd to the directory to where the script was downloaded and un-packed, probably your downloads folder. Then, move the script into the proper directory: /usr/lib/nx/ with:

```
  > sudo mv nxsetup /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup
```

Finally, make sure you change the ownership of this file once you moved it so that it is owned by root:

```
  sudo chown root:root /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup
```

Now use nxsetup to install necessary files and create the special user "nx"

```
  sudo /usr/lib/nx/nxsetup --install
```

Comment: same `keyserver.ubuntu.com: Connection timed out`

Comment: please see my update to the OP.