# How do I install FreeNX server so that it works correctly?

Tags: 10.10, authentication, openssh, freenx

I've tried every single possible way of installing the server now, I've read every how to available and I still can't get it to work. Please let me know in which step I do wrong. I'm using ubuntu 10.10. I will mainly be referring to the following [how-to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7930/how-can-i-install-freenx-server), but also [this](http://forums.techarena.in/guides-tutorials/1392442.htm), and [this one](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX).

- First I add the ppa
- Install Freenx
- Download the special Freenx package as stated in the howto, fix ownership - install it
- Create custom SSH key
- Copy the file /var/lib/nxserver/home/.ssh/client.id_dsa.key to the client and import it in nomachine (windows 7 x64)
- Check that both the user I will be logging in with and the user nx is in AllowedUsers in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
- Check the port that ssh is listening on
- Login through nomachine with my regular user account in ubuntu

I always receive the message "authentication failed for [user]" when I try to log in. And I can't see the user "nx" which is said to be created during installation when I look under System->Administration->"Users & Groups". Can anyone please enlighten me if there is any step that I miss or have misunderstood?

Thank you very much!

(Or is there an easier way of enabling remote desktop that it can be used with a windows machine? I prefer not using VNC because I was hoping of being able to get better performance than that. And when I tried using XRDP I only received a black screen on the client.)

Comment: One note, it looks like the correct property for sshd_config is AllowUsers, NOT AllowedUsers. I have hosed a half dozen ssh logins now using the wrong property name. My bad, but you might want to update that in your question.

Comment: i struggled with this all day, finally got it working. i am on ubuntu 10.04. the final step which allowed me to login was to enable challenge/response auth in sshd_config, i also allowed cleartext authorization. now just need to find out which one is required.

Comment: i have set PasswordAuthentication to no, so it looks like it only requires ChallengeResponseAuthentication to be turned on.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply the0ther! Hopefully this information will help many others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the nx user is a system user (id less than 1000) so he is not visible in System->Administration->"Users & Groups", you should see him in `/etc/passwd`.

Next, I use freenx server without custom ssh key, so I suggest to make it to work without the added complication of custom key. I restore my security using the firewall to deny access to non desired clients.

Comment: Ok, I will try that when I get home. Is NX really the best method for Remote Desktops?

Comment: I don't know why it works now but didn't before, I recently made a fresh install on the server and this time it works perfectly, even though I haven't done anything different :/

Answer (score -2):

teamveawer 6 (teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx) or Haguichi (only for Linux OS) (haguichi.net/download) + Hamachi 2 (secure.logmein.com/US/labs) remember if you choose to used the second one installing first hamachi2 and then haguichi.

Comment: I'm sorry but that was not at all what I was asking for :/